# Alexa Launch Skill issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, voice-recognition, alexa-voice-service

Trying to launch a skill I successfully built from the Alexa Dashboard, I'm getting the following:

[image]

[image]

This same invocation used to work and produced JSON Input just several hours ago.  Nothing has been changed and the endpoint for which the skill is configured is accessible.  I did try rebuilding the skill in the hopes it may fix the issue.

Alexa portal seems to [refer to a similar issue](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/165841/ask-test-there-was-an-issue-processing-your-input.html) w/o any pointers on what causes it and how to fix it.

**Updates:**

I tried renaming the invocation handle of the skill, saved, rebuilt and attempted to re-launch it. I activated the 'Device Log' checkbox.  The error didn't change - it still complains.  But the logs give a bit more of some (pretty useless) context.  Here's what I'm seeing now:

[image]

**[17:58:33:018] - Event: Text.TextMessage:**

```
    {
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Text",
            "name": "TextMessage",
            "messageId": "messageId",
            "dialogRequestId": "51a6476b-362b-4fbf-9125-7e5a36ea5649"
        },
        "payload": {
            "textMessage": "alexa open speech bank"
        }
    },
    "context": [
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "SpeechSynthesizer",
                "name": "SpeechState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "token": "",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0,
                "playerActivity": "PLAYING"
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "AudioPlayer",
                "name": "PlaybackState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "token": "",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0,
                "playerActivity": "IDLE"
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "Alerts",
                "name": "AlertsState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "activeAlerts": [],
                "allAlerts": []
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "AudioFocusManager",
                "name": "AudioFocusState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "alert": {
                    "component": null,
                    "idleTimeInMilliseconds": 0
                },
                "dialog": {
                    "component": "SpeechSynthesizer",
                    "idleTimeInMilliseconds": 1000
                },
                "content": {
                    "component": null,
                    "idleTimeInMilliseconds": 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**[17:58:33:847] - Error:**

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "System",
        "name": "Exception",
        "messageId": "bc7d2cda-2e1e-43fa-a82b-a417d29dfddc"
    },
    "payload": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION",
        "description": "Request could not be executed due to an internal service error."
    }
}
```

I am running the webhook endpoint in a debug mode to see whether the call reaches the handler there which doesn't seem to be the case.  The break point does get hit when invoked locally from Postman though.

**Another renaming attempt - removing spaces from the skill name:**

[image]

What could be the issue?

Where can I get a a bit more explanation of what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, the invocation name must be 2 words or more, so speechbank isn't a valid invocation. Also, when using single characters, use them like this: 'p. o. c.', it says both this right below the invocation box.

Comment: Can you try re-building the skill and test. Just ask "open speech bank". Also, is your skill a English-US skill ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a webhook's endpoint misconfiguration issue - a secure [Serveo](https://serveo.net/) proxy keeps rotating its server URL on a daily basis, it seems, so Alexa was confused by it.  But the message they display can certainly be improved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in both Chrome and Safari. It turned out to be my antivirus (Avast). I disabled the web shield and that fixed it.